# How self-inductance is possible in a Solenoid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

In a solenoid, when current changes with time an EMF is induced, but it should not be like this, because the wire which is bend to make solenoid is isolated (usually painted to give it an insulation) so each turn of solenoid is not completely a ***closed*** loop because the ends of the wire forming the turn are not joined, the coating is joined.

Comment: Each turn isn't a closed loop, but why should that be important? Induced electric field does not care, it is produced by accelerated current, so whether the turn closes itself or continues into another turn right next to it is almost immaterial, it just changes the induced electric field a little, due to different geometry of turn compared to closed loop.

Comment: Sir are you trying to say that if a C shaped loop is moved in magnetic field, the current will flow but will terminate when it come to ends ?

Comment: @Peterswift Yes, in a C-shaped wire there will be only a short current impulse.
 It will soon terminate, and then there is a positive charge in one half of the C,
 and a negative charge in the other half.

Comment: @Peterswift It is important to distinguish between motional EMF in the wire segment and current. There will be only very small and very short current impulse that separates charges and creates potential difference that counteracts the motional EMF. But motional EMF itself will be present as long as the wire moves in magnetic field.

Comment: Thank you so so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnetic flux $\Phi_B$ within the solenoid changes with time
(due to the current $I$ changing with time).
Now because of Faraday's induction law
$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=-\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$
a circular electric field $\vec{E}$ is induced.

[image]
<sub>(image from [Mini Physics - UY1: Induced Electric Field](https://www.miniphysics.com/uy1-induced-electric-field.html))</sub>

As @JanLalinsky commented, this electric field doesn't care why
the magnetic flux $\Phi_B$ is changing.
The electric field would be induced even if no wire would be there.

Of course the solenoid doesn't have $N$ distinct wires each forming a closed circle.
Instead it has one long wire forming a single spiral.
So the $N$ windings are connected in series,
and therefore the induced EMFs from all the windings add up,
and you get quite a large EMF between the two ends of the wire.

Comment: Sir does that mean, induced electric field will cause induced EMF ?

Comment: @Peterswift Yes, it does. And you can measure this EMF with a volt-meter.

Comment: Thank you sir i had a misconconception that EMF is only induced in closed loop. But,  E = -d(phi)/dt will not be applicable as one cannot define phi because it is not closed.

Comment: @Peterswift If you measure the EMF with a voltmeter, the voltmeter closes the loop.

Comment: @JohnDoty I think the term 'potential difference' will be suitable for open loop and 'EMF' for closed loop because in open loop one cannot point out the source that maintains the potential difference (EMF)

Comment: @Peterswift How do you measure the potential difference without closing the loop?